# Is there a standard Haskell function for (return a) >>= b?

Tags: haskell

I'm looking for a way to remove the `return`s from the following function:

```
  naming path = 
    getModificationTime path                       >>=
    return . formatTime defaultTimeLocale "%Y%m%d" >>=
    return . printf "%s_%s" (takeBaseName path)    >>=
    return . replaceBaseName path
```

The reason why I structure it this way is because `>>=` essentially becomes kind of a pipe operator and data flows from one line to the next.

I figured I can define an operator along the lines of

```
  a |>= b = (return a) >>= b
```

and get

```
  naming path = 
    getModificationTime path              >>=
    formatTime defaultTimeLocale "%Y%m%d" |>=
    printf "%s_%s" (takeBaseName path)    |>=
    replaceBaseName path
```

but I get the error

```
Precedence parsing error
    cannot mix `|>=' [infixl 9] and `.' [infixr 9] in the same infix expression
```

What's the best way to resolve this issue? Better yet, is there some sort of standard operator or other way to make it easier to structure the code this way?

Answer (score 8):

Presumably you want it to behave with the same fixity as `>>=`, so if you load up GHCi and type

```
> :info (>>=)
...
infixl 1 >>=
```

You could then define your operator as

```
infixl 1 |>=
(|>=) :: Monad m => a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
a |>= b = return a >>= b
```

But, if your monad preserves the monad laws, this is identical to just doing `b a`, so there isn't really a need for the operator in the first place.

I'd also suggest using do notation:

```
naming path = do
    modTime <- getModificationTime path
    let str = formatTime defaultTimeLocale "%Y%m%d" modTime
        name = printf "%s_%s" (takeBaseName path) str
    replaceBaseName path name
```

Answer (score 5):

You need the `return` because the whole rest of your chain composes pure functions, so the best way is to use the normal function composition operator [`.`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Prelude.html#v%3a-46-). However, `.` composes in the different direction compared to [`>>=`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Prelude.html#v%3a-62--62--61-) and since `>>=` is meant for composing two monadic operations you'll need at least one return:

```
naming path =
    getModificationTime path               >>=
    return                                 .
    replaceBaseName path                   .
    printf "%s_%s" (takeBaseName path)     .
    formatTime defaultTimeLocale "%Y%m%d"
```

One way to get rid of the extra `return` is to use [`<**>`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Control-Applicative.html#v%3a-60--42--42--62-) and [`pure`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Control-Applicative.html#v%3apure) from [`Control.Applicative`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Control-Applicative.html) instead of `>>=`.

```
naming path =
    getModificationTime path               <**> pure (
    replaceBaseName path                   .
    printf "%s_%s" (takeBaseName path)     .
    formatTime defaultTimeLocale "%Y%m%d"  )
```

To "fix" the order of operations to flow from top to bottom, we can replace `.` with [`>>>`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Control-Category.html#v%3a-62--62--62-) from [`Control.Category`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Control-Category.html), giving

```
naming path =
    getModificationTime path               <**> pure (
    formatTime defaultTimeLocale "%Y%m%d"  >>>
    replaceBaseName path                   >>>
    printf "%s_%s" (takeBaseName path)     )
```

Or, if you want to get crazy (using [`Control.Arrow`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Control-Arrow.html)):

```
naming path = flip runKleisli path $
    Kleisli getModificationTime            >>^
    formatTime defaultTimeLocale "%Y%m%d"  >>^
    replaceBaseName path                   >>^
    printf "%s_%s" (takeBaseName path)
```

Unfortunately, `Control.Applicative` doesn't provide a flipped version of [`<$>`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Data-Functor.html#v%3a-60--36--62-), but you can define it yourself to get a tidier version:

```
(<$$>) = flip (<$>)
infixr 1 <$$>

naming path =
    getModificationTime path               <$$>
    formatTime defaultTimeLocale "%Y%m%d"  >>>
    replaceBaseName path                   >>>
    printf "%s_%s" (takeBaseName path)
```

At which point we could just do this:

```
(|>=) = flip fmap

naming path =
    getModificationTime path              |>=
    formatTime defaultTimeLocale "%Y%m%d" |>=
    printf "%s_%s" (takeBaseName path)    |>=
    replaceBaseName path
```

Answer (score 4):

`return x >>= f` is the same as `f x`---in other words, most of your inner functions are pure and don't need `(>>=)` at all. Inside of `do` notation you use `let` to bind pure computations.

```
naming path = do
  time <- getModificationTime path
  let str  = formatTime defaultTimeLocale "%Y%m%d" time
      name = printf "%s_%s" (takeBaseName path) str
  replaceBaseName path name
```

To be even more concise, `name` above could be computed inline

```
naming path = do
  time <- getModificationTime path
  replaceBaseName path 
    $ printf "%s_%s" (takeBaseName path) 
    $ formatTime defaultTimeLocale "%Y%m%d" time
```

And we see that we're just doing some pure function composition, so we can use `(.)`

```
naming path = 
  getModificationTime path >>= replaceBaseName path . mkTime
  where
    mkTime = printf "%s_%s" (takeBaseName path) 
           . formatTime defaultTimeLocale "%Y%m%d"
```

If we didn't need `path` for `getModificationTime`, `replaceBaseName`, and `takeBaseName` we could shorten it even more by using just `(>=>)` to remove the `path` point entirely. That could still be done by using the `ReaderT` monad transformer, but it's likely to get uglier instead of nicer at this rate.

Comment: I know how to write it this way, using temporary variables or using `fmap`. But I'm trying to avoid writing it this way. The point is to try to get it to look like a pipe so it visually flows from one line to the next.

Comment: I'm continuing to refine it, but the ultimate idea is that you're really just doing pure function composition so you'll likely want to use `(.)`.