# How to mix Haskell monadic and pure filters in a piping fashion?

Tags: haskell, pipe, operator-keyword

In a previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20203056/is-there-a-standard-haskell-function-for-return-a-b), I tried to ask about how to mix pure and monadic functions by piping them together, but because I may have worded my question wrong and my example was too simplistic, I think the discussion went the wrong direction, so I think I'll try again.

Here is an example function that mixes pure and monadic filters. In this example, there are some pure filters sequenced in-between monadic filters to try to reduce the amount of work.

```
findFiles target = 
  getDirectoryContents target                    >>=
  return . filter (not . (=~ "[0-9]{8}\\.txt$")) >>=
  return . filter (=~ "\\.txt$")                 >>=
  filterM doesFileExist                          >>=
  mapM canonicalizePath
```

The benefit of writing it this way, where pure functions are mixed in using `return`, is that there is a *visual flow* of data from top to bottom. No need for temporary variables, `fmap`, `<$>` or the like.

Ideally, I can get rid of the `return`s to make it cleaner. I had the idea of using some operator:

```
(|>=) :: Monad m => a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
a |>= b = (return a) >>= b
```

But I don't know how to write this function to avoid operator precedence problems. Does this already exist? It is similar to `<$>` but the "other direction". If not, how do I make this operator work?

More generally, is there a good way to write code in this piping fashion, or need I settle for `fmap`s and temporary variables like as described in my previous question?

Answer (score 7):

Ugh. As simple as this:

```
infixl 1 |>=
(|>=) = flip fmap

findFiles target = 
  getDirectoryContents target           |>=
  filter (not . (=~ "[0-9]{8}\\.txt$")) |>=
  filter (=~ "\\.txt$")                 >>=
  filterM doesFileExist                 >>=
  mapM canonicalizePath
```

Answer (score 4):

Seconding DiegoNolan, there's no prize for the pointest-free code and no shame in using `do`-notation, binding intermediate values with either a monadic assignment (`x <- ...`) or a good old-fashioned `let`. The heirs to your code will thank you.

That said, if you can't bear points, you might be a category theorist. Seriously, you can take a page from John Hughes (see [Programming with Arrows](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/~rjmh/afp-arrows.pdf%E2%80%8E)) and write your pipeline like this:

```
import Control.Arrow

findFiles = runKleisli $
    Kleisli getDirectoryContents >>>
    arr (filter (not . (=~ "[0-9]{8}\\.txt$"))) >>>
    arr (filter (=~ "\\.txt$")) >>>
    Kleisli (filterM doesFileExist) >>>
    Kleisli (mapM canonicalizePath)
```

This is probably a little more principled than monkeying around with one's own special bind operators, but still uglier than the plain pointed style if you ask me. De gustibus non est disputandum, as the Romans always used to say about garum.

Comment: The problem with points here is that one will have to invent names for the intermediary stages for a pipeline that may not be in any way principled. In other words, we put things in a pipeline exactly because the intermediary stages are of so little significance we don't want to bother naming them.

Answer (score 1):

Use `(<$>)`, also known as `fmap`, for mapping pure functions into a functor.  Most monads have instances of functors.  If they don't have one then you can use `liftM`

Looking at the types

```
liftM :: Monad m => (a -> b) -> m a -> m b

(<$>) :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

Yours would look like this (haven't checken in ghc).

```
findFiles target = 
  ((filter (not . (=~ "[0-9]{8}\\.txt$")) .
  filter (=~ "\\.txt$")                 )        <$>
  getDirectoryContents target)                   >>=
  filterM doesFileExist                          >>=
  mapM canonicalizePath
```

But at this point you're probably just better off using do notation and `let`.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want a few extra operators, one to handle each case

```
Monad -> Monad
Monad -> Pure
Pure  -> Monad
Pure  -> Pure
```

You already have the `Monad -> Monad` case (`>>=`), and as I described in my answer to your last question, you could use `|>=` for the `Pure -> Monad` case, but you'll still need `Monad -> Pure` one.  That's going to be tricky, since the only type-safe way to do it is by having that operator transform your pure function into a monadic one.  I'd recommend the following set of operators

```
Monad -> Monad    >>=    m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
Monad -> Pure     >|=    m a -> (a ->   b) -> m b
Pure  -> Monad    |>=      a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
Pure  -> Pure     ||=    (a -> b) -> (b -> c) -> (a -> c)
```

Using the convention that `>` means "monad" and `|` means "pure", and all end with `=` meaning "to function".  Hopefully the type signatures will make sense with the implementations:

```
import Data.Char (toUpper)
import Control.Monad (liftM)

infixl 1 |>=
(|>=) :: Monad m => a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
a |>= b = b a

infixl 1 >|=
(>|=) :: Monad m => m a -> (a -> b) -> m b
a >|= b = liftM b a

infixr 9 ||=
(||=) :: (a -> b) -> (b -> c) -> a -> c
a ||= b = b . a
```

And an example

```
test :: IO ()
test =
    getLine             >|=
    filter (/= 't')     ||=
    map toUpper         >>=
    putStrLn

> test
testing
ESING
>
```

This is also equivalent to

```
test :: IO ()
test =
    getLine         >|=
    filter (/= 't') >|=
    map toUpper     >>=
    putStrLn
```

But the extra `||>` combination would let you actually compose those functions, which has a different implementation under the hood than feeding them through monadic actions.

However, I would *still* urge you to use the idiomatic way of doing this by using `fmap`, do notation, and temporary variables.  It'll be much clearer to anyone else that looks at the code, and that includes you in 2 months' time.